# Saving information from textBox to SESSION isn't working, probably a newbie mistake

Tags: php, session

I have two pages, A and B.

I want to echo a variable written in A inside of the page in B.

Here's the first page:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Registration Form - 1 of 2</title>
    </head>

<body>
    <h1>Registration - Part 1 of 2</h1>
    <p>Please fill in all the required information before submitting the information.</p>
    <form action="registerFormTwo.php" method="post">
        First Name:<input type="text" name="firstName" /><br /><?php $_SESSION['firstName'] = firstName; ?>
        Last Name:<input type="text" name="lastName" /><br /><?php $_SESSION['lastName'] = lastName; ?>
        Age:<input type="text" name="age" /><br /><?php $_SESSION['age'] = age; ?>
        Date of Birth:<input type="text" name="dateOfBirth" /><br /><?php $_SESSION['dateOfBirth'] = dateOfBirth; ?>

        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
```

**And here's the second one:**

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Registration Form - 2 of 2</title>
    </head>

<body>
    <h1>Registration - Part 2 of 2</h1>
    <p>Please fill in all the required information before submitting the information.</p>        
    <?php //wrote this in just to test that session information is saving, but it isn't.
    echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>

    <form action="registerFinish.php" method="post">
        Nationality<input type="text" name="nationality" /><br /><?php $_SESSION['nationality'] = nationality; ?>
        Profession:<input type="text" name="profession" /><br /><?php $_SESSION['profession'] = profession; ?>

        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
```

On the second page, the name variable should be echoed, but nothing shows.

Thank you for the help.

**EDIT:**

Here's the code on formOne and it's still not working:

```
<?php session_start();
if ($_POST) {
  // Store our name in the session array
  $_SESSION["firstName"] = $_POST["firstName"];
}
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Registration Form - 1 of 2</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Registration - Part 1 of 2</h1>
        <p>Please fill in all the required information before submitting the information.</p>
        <form action="registerFormTwo.php" method="post">
            First Name:<input type="text" name="firstName" /><br />
            Last Name:<input type="text" name="lastName" /><br /><?php $_SESSION['lastName'] = lastName; ?>
            Age:<input type="text" name="age" /><br /><?php $_SESSION['age'] = age; ?>
            Date of Birth:<input type="text" name="dateOfBirth" /><br /><?php $_SESSION['dateOfBirth'] = dateOfBirth; ?>

            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since "formOne" posts to "formTwo", you need to store the data to $_SESSION in "formTwo".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form data doesn't go directly into `$_SESSION`. You have to place it there. Since your form `method` is POST, you could pull your data out of `$_POST` on the server-side:

```
session_start();
if ($_POST) {
  // Store our name in the session array
  $_SESSION["name"] = $_POST["name"];
}
```

If you simply want to keep values in a form when the form submission failed, you don't need to use sessions. You can reprint the value from `$_POST` directly into the markup again:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php print $_POST["name"]; ?>" />
```

Keep in mind that all of this takes place on the *page that you're posting to*. If your first form is on `page1.php`, then you would ignore all of this. If you're posting from `page1.php` to `page2.php`, you would place the aforementioned code on `page2.php`.

**Update**

I just noticed the following beside your form elements:

```
<?php $_SESSION['lastName'] = lastName; ?>
```

`lastName` doesn't represent anything here. `$_POST["lastName"]` would represent the posted data. If you were trying to print the last-submitted value, I would do this:

```
<?php print $_POST["lastName"]; ?>
```